# changing navigator button titles per jqgrid

Tags: button, jqgrid, navigator

How do I change the title of a standard button (edit, add, delete) in the navigator on per grid basis? I want each jqGrid to have a different title and caption on that buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation of navGrid method which has the form:

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {parameters},
    prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

The `parameters` can include any value from [$.jgrid.nav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) (see the default values in the language dependent file `i18n/grid.locale-en.js`). So you can use for example

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager',
    { edittitle: "Edit selected order", addtitle: "Add new order" });
```